# In a one-to-one relationship, is it possible to check validations before deleting other children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, has-one

Just trying to get to the bottom of an issue I’ve been working on for a few days now. I have a has_one/belongs_to relationship, and the routes are nested. Normally, if there’s a has_many/belongs_to relationship, I could run something like:

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  @review = @movie.reviews.new(review_params)
end
```

in my controller with a nested resource.

However, I’ve noticed that this doesn’t work with a `has_one` association, since I don’t have a method named `review` on the @movie object. In other words, I can’t replicate the controller functionality in the same way by just using:

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  @review = @movie.review.new(review_params)
end
```

I’ve seen some alternatives like using `@movie.build_review` or `@movie.create_review` on this page: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one, but I’m having issues with that because it deletes the associated object as soon as it’s called, without checking validations. Curious if anyone has any advice for a possible solution. I’ve spent quite a while looking for a solution now, and the many things I’ve tried haven’t yielded anything substantial yet. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why don't you check if review is nil or not? if it's nil use `.build/create_review(review_params)` and if it's not nil use `.review.attributes = review_params`. I'm not sure what validations you want to check, you are not saving the objects on the code you show.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new review should happen in the `create` method, not in `new`.
You could do it in two steps so:

```
def create  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  @review.movie = @movie
  if @review.save
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie) # or somewhere else
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```